# Accelerating a Black Hole

Tags: electromagnetism, black-holes, acceleration

I believe I may have seen this question somewhere with the answer I am looking for, but I can't seem to find it here. If that's the case, then this question may be a duplicate.
I believe I read that it is possible to accelerate a black hole with electromagnetic forces, electric fields, something to that effect.
Other than through predominantly gravitation interactions, how can we accelerate a black hole through space?

Comment: If the black hole is charged, then you can use electromagnetic interactions.

Comment: Let me guess, "The Hole Man" by Niven?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz I haven't read much of Niven. I'm more of a contemporary reader, so more like Alastair Reynolds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Black holes can be accelerated by similar means as other objects apart from the fact that the acceleration cannot be a "continuous contact acceleration" such as when we use a hand to push something. (The issue is, of course, that our hand or any other pushing object would simply be eaten by the black hole.)

However, we can throw an object into the black hole, and the total momentum of the new system will be approximately conserved (up to possible gravitational waves and debris). So shoot a heavy enough object at sufficient speed, and the black hole will start moving. This will also work if you have a powerful wave of some field carrying momentum, such as an electromagnetic pulse (but the intensities of the field would have to be quite hard core). Similarly, the black hole will start moving if you place a heavy enough object in its vicinity to attract it.

Another possibility is if 1) the black hole is rotating, and 2) the black hole has electric charge. In case 1) the black hole acts as a "gravitomagnetic dipole", and will be repelled/attracted by other "gravitomagnetic dipoles" in very much the same way as in electromagnetism. We can then use a large, rapidly rotating mass to "push" the black hole exactly by this interaction. In case 2) the black hole can be, of course, also accelerated by other charges/ electromagnetic fields quite like in the case of a point charge.

---

To understand the behaviour of a black hole and how and why it will be accelerated differently in such interactions, consider the electromagnetic radiation to be of a much shorter wave-length than the Schwarzschild radius of the black hole and sending it in a plane-wave pattern onto a non-rotating black hole. The radiation can then be described as photons following null geodesics (light-rays).

We know from the computations of black hole shadows that the black hole will absorb all the photons that asymptotically start at a distance of $R_{shadow} = 5GM/c^2$ from the line that leads directly to the center of the black hole. The rest will then escape to infinity with no net effect on the sum of their momenta. If at infinity the four-momentum density flux of the wave is $s^\mu$, then we can simply write that the rate of change of the four-momentum of the black hole is
$$\frac{d p^\mu_{BH}}{dt} = s^\mu \pi R_{shadow}^2$$
Now consider, instead of a black hole, a simple flat circular surface perpendicular to the direction of the wave with radius $R_{shadow}$. This surface will partially absorb and partially reflect the incoming photons. When it absorbs the photon, it simply gets its four-momentum. However, if it *reflects* the photon, it gets approximately twice its spatial momentum, and almost none of its energy (zeroth component of four-momentum/ mass contribution). The approximation used is that we are interested in a time-interval where the total energy of all the reflected photons in the interval is small as compared to the mass-energy of the surface.

We can then approximately write
$$\frac{dp^0_{BH}}{dt} \approx \kappa s^0 \pi R_{shadow}^2$$
$$\frac{dp^i_{BH}}{dt} \approx \kappa s^i \pi R_{shadow}^2 + 2(1-\kappa)s^i\pi R_{shadow}^2$$
where $\kappa$ is the absorbed fraction of photons. So a completely absorbing surface ($\kappa=1$) of the right radius works the same as a black hole, but if it is reflecting, the object of the same "interaction radius" accelerates more than the black hole in the same field. (And it does not increase its proper mass as much as the black hole.)

Comment: Is there a difference between moving an object of some mass with a momentum-carrying EM field versus moving a rotating/non-rotating black hole of the same mass with the same field? For reasons ignorant I believe there is.

Comment: What I'm interested in is perhaps some description that relates a black hole's mass & charge to the momentum or energy in the field required to accelerate it by some rate.

Comment: That depends a little bit on how do you compare the two objects, but I gave a simple example in an edit to provide some intuition.

Comment: Your edit was indeed very insightful. Normally I would wait the customary day before accepting an answer, but I see no reason to, this suits the question phenomenally.